# rfkill blocks multiple adapters

Tags: wireless, rfkill

I have a usb wifi adapter as well as the built in one.  When I run `rfkill list` I get this output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
9: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Is there supposed to be a separate listing for the built in and usb adapters?  I want to be able to block just the built in adapter, right now when I run `rfkill block 0` it disables both adapters.

Update:
I found another old usb adapter, plugged that in, and ran `rfkill list`.  This time, the output was

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy2: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Where 4 is the 2nd adapter, I guess.  I'm using [this rtl8812au](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) repository for the driver.  Could there be a problem with that that causes the adapter to not show up in `rfkill list`?  With the 2nd adapter plugged in, I ran `rfkill block 4` and all wifi was blocked.  The built in wifi and the two adapters.  Is that how `rfkill` is supposed ti work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently how rfkill currently works for me, too. It's not only the rfkill command itself, which shows this behaviour. The same happens when you write directly into the sysfs files. For example (as root):

Disable RF on WiFi device #0:

```
$ echo 1 > /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/soft
```

Enable RF on WiFi device #2:

```
$ echo 0 > /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill2/soft
```

I'm assuming it's the default for all devices, which do not support the RF kill API in their driver. To quote from the cfg80211.h header file:

> RFkill integration in cfg80211 is almost invisible to drivers,
>   as cfg80211 automatically registers an rfkill instance for each
>   wireless device it knows about. Soft kill is also translated
>   into disconnecting and turning all interfaces off, drivers are
>   expected to turn off the device when all interfaces are down.

I, too, am using the rtl8812au driver as well as rtl8192ce, which both don't appear to support the RF kill API directly in their drivers.

To the rtl8812au driver itself, I'm using the one from https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au, because the one by [gnab](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) caused it to be identified as an Ethernet adapter instead of a WiFi adapter. If you're having the exact same issue then it might explain why it's not listed by rfkill.

Comment: Wow, you really did your research.  Thank you.